# Laravel - POSTMAN is returning 500 Internal Server Error on POST Request

Tags: laravel, postman

I have written POST Request endpoint in Laravel-5.8 for user login.
This is the location of the file:

> localhost:8888/tsl-clientportal-app/clientportal-backend

AuthCoontroller.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Notifications\SignupActivate;
use Avatar;
use Storage;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        $credentials['active'] = 1;
        $credentials['deleted_at'] = null;
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();

        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(13);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString(),
            'data'          => $user
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

api.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::get('signup/activate/{token}', 'AuthController@signupActivate');

    Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

When I tested the Request on POSTMAN, I expected to see the success result. But I got the error shown in the diagram below:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Pk7.png)

Comment: Try to send the data as json format .

Comment: @farooq - how do I do that?

Comment: Do you get any error in the laravel error log? storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: @rypskar - No, I did not see any error

Comment: Have you also checked your web-server log?

Comment: Your web server and/or PHP logs will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel web routes requires "XSRF-TOKEN" in request header, so for testing in POSTMAN you should send "XSRF-TOKEN=value" in Cookie key in header of request.

Like:
If you store your sessions in Cookies, you can grab the Cookie from an auth request in Developer Tools.
[image]

and then in postman
[image]

**OR you use csrf_token() value in "_token" key in header**
[image]

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In general(not scoped just to this question) it can have many reason and the most common thing is that `your connection to your db is disable`.

For example in xampp you should start Mysql or other dbs...

Yes.its too simple but very most common mistake:)